# Difference between "dispatcherServlet" and "appServlet" in spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Difference between "dispatcherServlet" and "appServlet" in spring MVC. Can I get any samples or references?

Comment: Spring MVC doesn't define any component called "appServlet", your question is unclear.

Comment: In web.xml file, we can give "<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name><servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>"
 like this. I think now my question is clear ??

Comment: You seem to be aware that "appServlet" is just the name you used for your DispatcherServlet, so no, it's not clear what you mean exactly. Since you're happy with the accepted answer then fair enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically both are  **HttpServlet** implementation to handle incoming requests. **DispatcherServlet** is Spring provided servlet implemenation having all essential features like exception handling ..
You have to just write your Request mappers ,it will handle all request.

**AppServlet** is nothing different, just your implementation for specific handling of requests.
Both will work in same way .If you dont have any specific handling than you can just go with Spring DispatcherServlet.

For example..

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

```
<!-- Custom Servlet -->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>CustomServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.abc.CustomServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>debug</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>any-other-Parameter</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/myapp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>CustomServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/myapp2/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

For reference of **DispatcherServlet** you can see http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 0):

to understand this, you can have a look on below configuration :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

In above configuration DispatcherServlet is the servlet class provided by spring framework.

> The job of the DispatcherServlet is to take an incoming URI and find the 
>   right combination of handlers (generally methods on Controller classes) 
>   and views (generally JSPs) that combine to form the page or resource 
>   that's supposed to be found at that location.

while **appServlet** is the custom name given by you in your web.xml file.